# C# with antlr4 parse mysql,use mysql-workbench grammars

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, antlr4

I use antlr4 grammar is mysql-workbench.
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars

The cmd as follows

```sh
java -Xmx1024m -jar antlr4-4.7.2.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp -listener -visitor -o ./mysql -package MyAntlr4 MySQLLexer.g4 MySQLParser.g4
```

However，I miss the class `MySQLBaseLexer`, `MySQLBaseRecognizer`. How can I get the **Class file**。

Answer (score 0):

These classes [exist only in C++](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/mysql). You have to port them over to C# yourself. However, they are only support classes for a few things like predicates, server version etc. So, it should be fairly easy to do the translation. Also, it would be enough to only port the necessary parts. Not every helper function in those classes is required to use the MySQL grammar.